# How to estimate how many ACUs I will need for an RDS Aurora Postgress Serverless V2 writer instance?

Tags: estimation, aws-aurora-serverless

I need to estimate costs for an Aurora Postgress Serverless V2 database capable of doing 200 small DB inserts a second (around 300 bytes each, only one PK constraint on the table). The main cost driver will be the amount of ACUs needed to handle the throughput. Is it possible to guess how many I may need? I don't need to be that exact. I can be factor 2-4 away from the actual number.